# How to refresh a method for each 5 second without refreshing a page?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

I just have a simple method called `a()`.I need to refresh this method for each 5 second.So I used `setInterval` here.Its working fine.

```js
a();

setInterval(function () {
  a();
}, 5000)

function a() {
  alert('method refreshed!!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Issue is if I do any any changes in that method and save it,changes are not updating until I refresh the page.

eg.I remove alert() from my method and save it but alert() box is fired until I refresh the page.
But I want to update the changes without refreshing the page.How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by `method refresh`. Do you mean to execute this method at an interval?

Comment: If change the script then you have to refresh the page. To take changes affect you have to refresh the page

Comment: How you removed the alert from the function a()?

Comment: I guess OP edits `a()` method through console.

Comment: It's not possible just because of your new code need to refresh to execute. and updating code doesn't means it will run updated code.

Comment: can I do it in angular?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to save the reference to the initial `setInterval` in order to clear it and start an interval again with the new function.

```js
function a1() {
  console.log('first a');
}
a1();
const firstInterval = setInterval(a1, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  function a2() {
    console.log('second a');
  }
  clearInterval(firstInterval);
  const secondInterval = setInterval(a2, 1000);
}, 2500);
```

Another option is to simply reassign `a`, like this:

```js
let a = () => console.log('first a');
a();
const firstInterval = setInterval(() => {
  a();
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  a = () => console.log('second a');
}, 2500);
```

(you have to use a function expression (`a = () =>` or `a = function() {`) rather than a function declaration (`function a() {`) because function declarations are hoisted.)

But still, try to avoid reassigning your functions, it's pretty bad practice.